# OSX - Publishing Unity Games

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

How do I push Unity Games for Mac OSX to the Mac Store? I can't seem to figure out and have looked every where. I know you have to modify the info.plist and package, but there is no definitive guide!

thanks
NB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Submit App to Mac Store:

1. Build in Unity for Mac Intel Only
2. Show Package Contents of the .app once Compiled from Unity

2.a. Edit Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0.0</string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string>public.app-category.sports-games</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string>© 2012 Apollo Software Solutions. All rights reserved.</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.apolloss.GolfProHD</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0.0</string>
```

2.b. Replace Resources/UnityPlayer.icns with one that is 1024x1024 (you may need icns editor/generator)

2.c. Change permissions on /Data for "everyone" from "no access" to be "Read only"

1. In Terminal… (you may need entitlements, if so create entitlements xml file and add to codesign command).

   codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Amit Barman" GolfProHD.app

   productbuild --component GolfProHD.app /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer    Installer: Amit Barman" GolfProHD.pkg

***Delete the .app file after productbuild has created the .pkg (or the installer test will not work).***

sudo installer -store -pkg GolfProHD.pkg -target /

1. Verify that your app is installed in Applications
2. Ready to submit the .pkg to iTunes Connect!

Comment: point to note: as @AppolloSoftware has said,  the app should be deleted in the current directory and subsequent parent directory to test install it, else, it will simple replace it in the existing directory. I missed this part and wasted 2 hours figuring out why its not installing in `Applications` directory